# How to set same attributes to multiple variables using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 12 div that must have the same attributes and i don't find the way to simplify my code.
In this example below the variables 'blue' and 'red' have both the same 3 settings and i would like to know if there is a way to declare the setAttributes once instead of 12 times.

```
let blue = document.getElementById('blue');
blue.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration : underline');
blue.setAttribute('style', 'color : #00ff00');
blue.setAttribute("href", "#zag");

let red = document.getElementById('red');
red.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration : underline');
red.setAttribute('style', 'color : #00ff00');
red.setAttribute("href", "#zag");
```

Comment: instead of id you can use class of the element.

Comment: Maybe show your markup in your question so we have a better understand of your use-case. For example you shouldn't be putting `href` attributes on `div` elements.

Comment: Use a function or a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop ... Create an array with all ids you want to update. The iterate over the collection and get the element for each id.

```
let ids = ['blue', 'red', ...];
for (let id of ids) {
  let elem = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!elem) continue;

  elem.setAttribute(...);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! it perfectly works :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a for loop:

```js
const elementIds = ["blue", "red"]

for (let elementId of elementIds) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration : underline');
    element.setAttribute('style', 'color : #00ff00');
    element.setAttribute("href", "#zag");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i took the solution proposed by derpirscher